# How are lambda expressions vs method group statements evaluated differently?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm trying to learn more about how lambdas work in C# and I'm a bit confused by the following example.

I have a weighted average function:

```
public static double? WeightedAverage<T>(this IEnumerable<T> records, Func<T, double?> value, Func<T, double?> weight)
{
    // snip actual calculation code
    if (denominator != 0)
        return numerator / denominator;
    return null;
}
```

In one place, I use a helper function that has a return type of `double`:

```
static double GetQuantity(Record record)
{
    return record.Quantity * record.Factor;
}
```

And pass that as the `weight` parameter into the weighted average function like this:

```
return _records.WeightedAverage(r => r.Price, r => ReportHelpers.GetQuantity(r));
```

The above seems to work fine.

The part that is confusing to me: In a few places ReSharper has recommended that I convert some of my lambdas into method groups. Playing around to try and see how this works, I changed the call to:

```
return _records.WeightedAverage(r => r.Price, ReportHelpers.GetQuantity);
```

This results in an error, `Expected a method with 'double?' GetQuantity(Record) signature`

Can someone tell me exactly what is happening behind the scenes here? Why does the lambda expression not produce a similar error since the return of the `GetQuantity` function is `double` and not `double?`? What is the difference with how the method group vs lambda expressions are being evaluated?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a very valid question. I looked at the [relevant section of the C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions), but could not find a reason why this is not allowed... I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda expression doesn't have the error because its return type is inferred to be `double?`, matching the delegate argument, and you are explicitly returning a double from your method call. It works for the same reason that this works:

`static double? GetDoubleOrNull() => 0.0d;`

A double is a valid value for a nullable double to have.

A method group conversion, however, has additional rules that it needs to satisfy and, because it's trying to match a delegate, one of them is [delegate compatibility.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/delegates#delegate-compatibility) In particular, there is a line that says:

> An identity or implicit reference conversion exists from the return type of M to the return type of D.

There is no identity or implicit reference conversion between `double` and `double?`, so the method group conversion fails. There *is* an implicit nullable conversion, but that isn't applicable here.